# Поддомены с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

имеем сайт со страницей site.ru/123.html
нужно сделать так, чтобы эта страница отрабатывалась как поддомен 123.site.ru

Это можно сделать через htaccess?
Алиасы я прописал в настройках vds *.site.ru, так что папки site.ru/12345 работают, как 12345.site.ru, теперь нужно файлы перевести в формат поддоменов.

Comment: http://htmlweb.ru/php/htaccess_subdomain.php

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.site\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1 [L]
```

Под рукой нету сервера, что бы проверить

Comment: Увы, но не работает скрипт :(